# purrr::map removes CRS from sf data frame r? / increase efficiency in st_intersection()

Tags: r, performance, spatial

I'm trying to find the overlapping areas of elements in an sf data frame and a separate polygon. In my real example, both files are quite complex, so it's super slow - I've been trying to find ways to speed it up (parallelizing functions, vectorizing functions), but I think I'm confusing myself and I'm not sure there are faster methods than `sf`'s native functions.

I'm trying to set up the `st_intersect` in a `map` or `apply` function so that I can convert it to parallel processing with `furrr` or `parallel::mcapply()`, but i'm having trouble. My questions are twofold, with a simple reprex below.

set up reprex objects:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
# get world map
world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf") 
# make rectangle
poly <-  st_polygon(list(cbind(c(-80,80,80,-80,-80), c(20,20,-20,-20,20)))) %>%
  st_sfc(crs =st_crs(world) )

# convert both to mollweide projection since st_intersection doesn't like lat/lon
world_moll <- world %>%
  st_transform(st_crs("+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0"))
st_agr(world_moll) <- "constant"
poly_moll <- poly %>%
  st_transform(st_crs(world_moll))
rm(world,poly)
```

QUESTION 1: when I try to `apply()` or `map()` across the `world$geometry` column, the CRS value for the geometries seems to have disappeared. Why is this? How do I fix it?

```
# try to map `st_intersection` over geometry column, but get error that objects don't have the same crs 
purrr::map(.x = world_moll$geometry,
           .f = ~st_intersection(.x, poly_moll))

# same issue using lapply:
lapply(world_moll$geometry,
       FUN = function(x) st_intersection(x, poly_moll))

# however, when I check it a couple of different ways, the crs values for each world geometry and poly_moll should be equal 
setequal(st_crs(world_moll), st_crs(poly_moll))
setequal(st_crs(world_moll$geometry[1]), st_crs(poly_moll))

# use purrr or apply to pull geometries for each world row:
purrr::map(.x = world_moll[["geometry"]],
           .f = ~st_crs(.x))
lapply(world_moll$geometry,
       FUN = function(x) st_crs(x))
# all crs values come out as NA -- why??
```

QUESTION 2: is this even possible to parallelize or vectorize to increase efficiency or is simply running `st_intersection` on the original dataframe my best bet for quick processing?

I've put 4 example methods of finding intersections in the reprex here. the fastest by a lot remains simply `st_intersection(x,y)` so I think maybe I have overcomplicated this whole issue.

```
# method 1 ----------------------------------------------------------------
# use st_intersection on entire sf dataframe
system.time(
   intersections_method1 <- 
    world_moll %>%
    st_make_valid() %>%
    st_intersection(poly_moll)
)

#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.082   0.002   0.086 



# method 2  ---------------------------------------------------------------
# here, I loop through rows and save in a list, then rebind list into a dataframe
# this is much slower, but I like that I can see where errors arise. 
# is this helpful at all? is there a way to parallelize a for loop to multiple cores? 

system.time({
world_intersections <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(world_moll)){
  
  world_intersections[[i]] <- 
    world_moll[i,] %>%
    st_make_valid() %>%
    st_intersection(poly_moll)
  print(world_moll$name_en[i])
  
}
intersections_method2 <- do.call(rbind, world_intersections)
})
#  user  system elapsed 
#  3.665   0.454   4.459 


# method 3 - try foreach --------------------------------------------------
library(foreach)
system.time({
intersections_method3 <- 
  foreach(i = 1:nrow(world_moll),
          .combine = 'rbind') %do% {
            world_moll[i,] %>%
              st_make_valid() %>%
              st_intersection(poly_moll)
          }
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  3.094   0.236   3.424 
# still much slower than option 1



# method 4 - foreach in parallel --------------------------------------------------

# set up parallel backend
library(parallel)
detectCores()
ncores <- detectCores() -2
#create the cluster
mycluster <- parallel::makeCluster(
  ncores, 
  type = "FORK"
)

#check cluster definition (optional)
print(mycluster)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl = mycluster)

system.time({
  intersections_method4 <- 
    foreach(i = 1:nrow(world_moll),
            .combine = 'rbind') %dopar% {
              world_moll[i,] %>%
                st_make_valid() %>%
                st_intersection(poly_moll)
            }
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.216   0.022   1.520 
# still slower than method 1 - why?? 


# show that all outputs are the same:
setequal(intersections_method1,
         intersections_method2)
setequal(intersections_method2,
         intersections_method3)
setequal(intersections_method3,
         intersections_method4)
```

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::select` instead of the `$` operator to retain the CRS:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(purrr)

    the_intersections <- 
      world_moll |>
      select(geometry) |> ## !
      map(~ .x |>
              st_make_valid() |> ## otherwise e.g. Sudan throws an error
              st_intersection(poly_moll)
          ) |>
      (\(l) do.call(rbind, l))() |>
       st_sfc()
```

```
    
    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot() + geom_sf(data = the_intersections)
```

[image: cropped world map]

**however** for mere visualisation you could just `st_crop` the world vector *in a fraction of the time*:

```
world_moll_cropped <-
    world_moll |>
      st_make_valid() |>
      st_crop(poly_moll)
```

Moreover you could `st_simplify` the world data unless you really need the high resolution.

Comment: thanks for the fix re split(). Using the split-to-map code above, that process is still way slower than world_moll %>% st_intersection(poly_moll), so I'm still a bit generally confused why purrr doesn't seem to help with speed, or what the point of it is, really. You did solve my map() problem, though, thank you.

Comment: Please see edit; just realised that with `dplyr::select` instead of `$` to extract the geometry, mapping becomes really fast.

Comment: I'm afraid it becomes so fast with `select` as it basically cancels `map()`, `map()` now iterates over sf object columns and as there's just one of those ...

Answer (score 1):

For `map()` (and for parallel processing), I'd guess the focus should be on the splitting strategy of the dataset. Splitting into a list of single-item `sf` / `sfc` can't be ideal, I can't come up with a proper apples-to-apples benchmark, but in addition to the added overhead of managing `nrow()` number of sf-objects, I'd expect [spatial indexing](https://r-spatial.org/r/2017/06/22/spatial-index.html) to be rendered useless as well.

Not sure how well included reprex models your real-world problem, for a somewhat different setting here's a nice piece on using `{sf}` with `{furrr}` : https://posit.co/blog/geospatial-distributed-processing-with-furrr/

But we can still check what's happening with CRS and perhaps consider some alternative packages, like `{geos}`. To see any measurable gain from parallel processing, I believe the test dataset is just way too small and simple, most of that time is just spent on the added overhead.

Reprex with `{giscoR}` to work with valid geometries:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(geos)

# country shapes from giscoR, those geometries should be valid;
# add un.region.name column that will later used for a grouping
world_moll <- left_join(giscoR::gisco_countries, 
                   giscoR::gisco_countrycode[, c("ISO3_CODE", "un.region.name")]) %>% 
  mutate(un.region.name = tidyr::replace_na(un.region.name, "NA")) %>% 
  st_transform("+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0")
#> Joining with `by = join_by(ISO3_CODE)`

# make rectangle
poly_moll <-  st_polygon(list(cbind(c(-80,80,80,-80,-80), c(20,20,-20,-20,20)))) %>% 
  st_sfc(crs = "WGS84") %>% 
  st_transform(crs = st_crs(world_moll))
```

So, what's happening with CRS when using `map()` on a geometry set?

```r
# when using map() on a geometry column (sfc), it will iterate through sfg objects:
map(world_moll$geometry, class) %>%  first()
#> [1] "XY"           "MULTIPOLYGON" "sfg"

# so instead of testing CRS attribute of a single-item list ...
setequal(st_crs(world_moll$geometry[1]), st_crs(poly_moll))
#> [1] TRUE

# ... we should test against a single list item ([] vs [[]]):
setequal(st_crs(world_moll$geometry[[1]]), st_crs(poly_moll))
#> [1] FALSE

# CRS is an attribute of sfc and 
# a single geometry list item (sfg) is indeed without CRS:
st_crs(world_moll$geometry[[1]])
#> Coordinate Reference System: NA
attributes(world_moll$geometry[[1]])
#> $class
#> [1] "XY"           "MULTIPOLYGON" "sfg"
```

To use `map()` and to prepare for parallel processing, we could group / split the dataset first and then apply `st_intersection()` on a list of `sf` objects.
For comparison let's include `sf::st_intersection()` as well as `geos::geos_intersection()` :

```r
# group / split the dataset by region:
world_regions <- world_moll %>% 
  group_by(un.region.name) %>% 
  group_split()
str(world_regions, max.level = 0)
#> List of 6

# use list of sf objects with map(), returns an sf object; 
# let's pack it into test_map_sf_list() function for later benchmarking
test_map_sf_list <- function(x, y){
  map(x, st_intersection, y) %>% bind_rows()
}

# st_intersection for reference, returns an sf object:
test_st_isect <- function(x, y){
  st_intersection(x, y)
}

# geos::geos_intersection(), 
# returns geos_geometry, which can be converted back to sf / sfc:  
test_geos_isect <- function(x, y){
  geos_intersection(as_geos_geometry(x),  as_geos_geometry(y))
}
geos_isect <- test_geos_isect(world_moll, poly_moll)
# returned geometry length is same as for x and it also includes empty polygons: 
str(geos_isect)
#>  geos_geometry[1:257] <POLYGON EMPTY>, <POLYGON EMPTY>, <POLYGON EMPTY>, <POLYG
plot(geos_isect)
```

[image]

##### Benchmark

Just to get an idea of timing difference,
returned values or not the same, so `check = FALSE`

```r
bm <- bench::mark(
  test_map_sf_list(world_regions, poly_moll),
  test_st_isect(world_moll, poly_moll),
  test_geos_isect(world_moll, poly_moll),
  check = FALSE
) 

bm
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression                            min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                        <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 test_map_sf_list(world_regions, … 124.6ms 180.3ms      5.55    2.48MB     2.77
#> 2 test_st_isect(world_moll, poly_m…  42.1ms  46.3ms     21.1     1.71MB     2.11
#> 3 test_geos_isect(world_moll, poly…  15.8ms  16.3ms     60.8     32.2KB     0
plot(bm)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>